# Why do I hear static when I plug in my earphones incorrectly?

Tags: acoustics, home-experiment, electronics, electrical-engineering, noise

I use simple earphones which are wired with my laptop. Most of the times I unconsciously plug them in without looking and at times instead of going in the port they touch the laptop body near the port instead. Whenever I do so I hear some static in the earphones as I've already tucked them in my ears. What's the reason for this?

Comment: Improper signal grounding and just charges are flowing where they're not supposed to be and your earphone speakers are sensitive enough to respond. Static, for example.

Comment: @DKNguyen does this mean my laptop body is leaking out charges? I sometimes so get a light shock at one of the edges of the laptop, is this also a consequence of this?

Comment: Not necessarily. Remember that your earphone speakers respond to an audio signal that is only a few volts. Humans can only feel static shocks that are as low as about 3000V. So there's a lot of static discharge that you cannot feel that your earphones are sensitive enough to react to.

Comment: @DKNguyen Alrighty! Thanks

Comment: FYI: Old-school [piezoelectric earphones](https://www.musicalinstrumentshoppe.com/product/1693194/) and headphones can reproduce audible sound from [signals containing only _picowatts_ of energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio#Basic_principles).

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks had no idea about this